# Camera stops immediately

Tags: camera

First of all I do not want to do anything with pathing simply because I am still super new to Blender. I am doing it the simple way where I keyframe my camera in blender so I get point A to point B. However, once my camera reaches point B the position of the camera stops immediately and doesn't slow down right before it reaches point B. Making it look unprofessional. Any way I can do this without using the pathing tool of any sort. Thanks for the help!

Comment: change the interpolation for the keyframes to bezier.

Comment: watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9gCHhJOjlQ

Comment: WOW...Thanks guys I really appreciate it! Good luck on your projects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Curve editor select the keyframs and press <kbd>T</kbd> to change the interpolation for the keyframes to **bezier**

[image]